# How can I read flask session variable from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have no idea, my flask project writes in a specific flask session variable, called 'card', some data, that for each client I've to display on the client side.

Comment: You should give the documentation a read - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your client side.
But you can pass Python variables as arguments of the "return" :

```
@app.route("/")
def route_default():
    #some code here
    
    return render_template(index.html, myvar=session["card"])
```

then on your html file (index.html) refer to the variable between a double curl braket : {{myvar}} :

```
<h1>
    card name is : {{myvar}}
</h1>
```